# Length of line segments in gnuplot's postscript output

Tags: gnuplot, postscript, inkscape, eps

I plot datafiles (i.e. timeseries) with gnuplot and the postscript eps enhanced terminal. When I'd like to modify these graphics with inkscape, e.g. changing the color of the lines, it's tiring because the lines are split to segments with 100 points each. This means I cannot change the color of the entire line at once.

Is there a possibility to change the default line-segment length or is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: An explanation from the source code about this behaviour: "Ghostscript has a 'pile-up of rounding errors' bug: a sequence of many rmove's or rlineto's does not yield the same line as move's or lineto's. Therefore, we periodically force an update of the absolute position. There was a case when 400 rlineto's were too much, [...]. This runs into a second ghostscript bug, that mixing relative and absolute lineto with no intervening 'stroke' is ridiculously slow to render. So we stroke the partial line, update the position in absolute terms, then continue."

Answer (score 0):

just found the solution:

```
sed -i 's/\(stroke\ [0-9]*\ [0-9]*\ M\)/%\1/g' FILENAME.eps
```

This prevents the lines being disconnected

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution.  Sorry that I misunderstood what you were asking about.